# How can I pass my students array of objects through methods in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

i'm new in Java (1-2 days) and I want to know how can I pass an array of objects through methods. When I compile the code ,I receive "class ,enum expected" or something like this.  To be specific ,I want to read the students info ,then to show off its info through another method.
P.S. Sorry for duplicate ,but I actually can't understand from any answered question.

```
package javalearning;

import java.util.Scanner;

public void showStudents(int n) {
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
            System.out.println("Student #"+i+" has "+s[i].getAge()+" and he is in "+s[i].getStudy()+" year !");
    }
}

public class JavaLearning {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int i;
      String name;
      System.out.println("Insert number of students: ");
      Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
      int N = n.nextInt();
      for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
           Student[] s = new Student[N];
           s[i] = new Student();
           System.out.println("Age: ");
           Scanner _age = new Scanner(System.in);
           int AGE = _age.nextInt();
           System.out.println("Year of study: ");
           Scanner _year = new Scanner(System.in);
           int YEAR = _year.nextInt();
           s[i].setAge(AGE);
           s[i].setYearOfStudy(YEAR); 
      }
      showStudents(N);
    } 
}
```

And here is the Students class:

```
package javalearning;

public class Student {
    public int age;
    public int yearOfStudy;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int _age) {
        this.age = _age;
    }
    public int getYearOfStudy() {
        return yearOfStudy;
    }
    public void setYearOfStudy(int y){
        this.yearOfStudy = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) `showStudents` is a method outside of any class... You can't do that. 2) `Student[] s = new Student[N];` should be **outside** any loop

Comment: @Newbie1234 Why? That is the Enum class and not needed here

Comment: @Newbie1234 I'm not following. Do what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments within the code :

```
public class JavaLearning {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //code removed
    } 

    //method should be INSIDE the class 
    public static void showStudents(int n, Student[] s) { //path Student array
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
                System.out.println("Student #"+i+" has "+s[i].getAge()+" and he is in "+s[i].getStudy()+" year !");
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: (method also needs to be static)

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it. My mistake: yes it needs to be static to be refered to from other static (i.e `main`) method

Comment: I did what you say ,but now I receive an error "Could not find symbol" at `getStudy()` from showStudents() method

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is move your `showStudents` inside class definition then try again.  You cannot define a method outside classs definition.